How can I list all connected emacsclients?
If I have two emacsclients connected to an Emacs server, is there any way to list them?
The variable server-clients displays this when an emacsclient is connected.
server-clients is a variable defined in ‘server.el’.

Its value is (#<process server <1>>)

List of current server clients.
Each element is a process.

Can I somehow interact with this list? Can I force a disconnect, for example?
I also have a command called server-list-clients, but that only gives me:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range ["server <1>" "open" "--" "--" "(network connection to t)"] 5)
  tabulated-list-print-entry(#<process server <1>> ["server <1>" "open" "--" "--" "(network connection to t)"])
  #<subr tabulated-list-print>(nil nil)
  ad-Advice-tabulated-list-print(#<subr tabulated-list-print>)
  apply(ad-Advice-tabulated-list-print #<subr tabulated-list-print> nil)
  tabulated-list-print()
  (save-current-buffer (set-buffer buffer) (client-menu-mode) (setq process-menu-query-only query-only) (server-list-clients--refresh) (tabulated-list-print))
  server-list-clients()
  funcall-interactively(server-list-clients)
  call-interactively(server-list-clients record nil)
  command-execute(server-list-clients record)
  counsel-M-x-action("server-list-clients")
  ivy-call()
  ivy-read("M-x " ("server-list-clients" "org-edna-mode" "org-insert-subheading" "ytdl-download" "org-property-action" "org-mark-ring-goto" "all-over-the-screen" "point-undo" "mpc-songs-search" "dogears-back" "customize-variable" "mpc-playlist-add" "org-journal-new-entry" "better-jumper-jump-backward" "visual-line-mode" "emacspeak-speak-line" "my-org-agenda-next-day" "eww" "chatgpt-shell" "typing-of-emacs" "etm-eww-html-to-org" "replace-symbol-with-kill-ring" "insert-escaped-kill-ring" "package-refresh-contents" "wg-echo-current-workgroup" "wg-load" "detour-back" "typit-basic-test" "cc/move-word-backward" "comint-previous-prompt" "org-web-tools-archive-attach" "osg" "wg-save" "obtt-tangle" "purpose-mode" "dired-du-mode" "flyspell-mode" "redacted-mode" "org-agenda-goto" "w3m-view-source" "dired-quick-sort" "bongo-insert-file" "eww-toggle-images" "monkeytype-fortune" "wg-create-workgroup" "wiktionary-bro-dwim" "toggle-truncate-lines" "imagex-sticky-maximize" "yeetube-download-video" "wiktionary-bro-at-point" ...) :predicate counsel--M-x-externs-predicate :require-match t :history counsel-M-x-history :action counsel-M-x-action :keymap (keymap (67108908 . counsel--info-lookup-symbol) (67108910 . counsel-find-symbol)) :initial-input nil :caller counsel-M-x)
  counsel-M-x()
  funcall-interactively(counsel-M-x)
  call-interactively(counsel-M-x nil nil)
  command-execute(counsel-M-x)


It depends on what you mean by "list them". What do you want to know?

You asked a question (just the first sentence of the current form of the question asking for a way to "list" the clients). I asked you for clarification, which you did not provide. @g-gundam then provided an answer (prematurely IMO), which you then used to modify the question. Please don't do that: provide clarification in a timely manner when asked; accept the answer (strictly speaking, and in the absence of any clarification on your part, the answer does answer the original question even though the only useful information you get is how many clients are connected); if you need more ...

... information, ask a separate question.

You can look at the elisp variable server-clients to see a list of currently connected clients.
See C-h v server-clients for more details.
